# Redirect extends url instead of changing it

Tags: django, apache, python-3.x, mod-wsgi

Let's say that on `mysite.com/my_view/` I can log into my system.

In development everything was fine. In production I end with `mysite.com/my_view/mysite.com/admin`in my url bar in browser. :(

My "log in" code looks like:

```
def my_view(request):
    domain="mysite.com"
    return redirect("http://"+domain+"/admin/")
```

Comment: I don't think it has to do with your code. It should be either DNS name provider or your server

Comment: Probably you're right. As I understand from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect) redirect returns 302 status code, which (i guess) is handled by Apache..

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it has to do with your code. It should be either DNS name provider or your server.

My guess is that when registering your domain name, you submitted a relative path, like this:

```
yoursite.com
```

When you should have done this:

```
http://yoursite.com
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It fixed by itself after some time... Apache is still mysterious for me, my host provider says that he didn't do anything with that :x.